# Javascript error: 'window.top.document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I am getting a javascript error when I attempt to click on my calendar control.

**The html code is:**

```
        <td align="left" style="width:50%;"><asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="TextFontBold" ID="lblStartDate" Text="Start Date:"></asp:Label>
            <input type="text" class="TextBox" id="FromDate" runat="server"/><a href="javascript:ShowCalendar('FromDate1')"><img src="images/Calendar.png" border="0" /></a>
            <iframe src="Calendar.aspx?DateTextID=FromDate" style="display:none; top: 0px; left: 0px; width:245px; height:164px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="FromDate1" id="FromDate1"></iframe>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="TextFontBold" ID="lblPromoStartTime" Text="Start Time:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
```

When I click on a date in the calendar control, this code is executed on the code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calendar1.SelectionChanged
    Dim strjscript As String = "<script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"">"
    strjscript &= "window.top.document.getElementById('" & HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("DateTextID") & "').value = '" & Calendar1.SelectedDate & "';"
    strjscript &= "window.top.document.getElementById('" & HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("DateTextID") & "1').style.display = 'none';"
    strjscript = strjscript & "</script" & ">"
    Literal1.Text = strjscript
End Sub
```

The error I am getting is **'window.top.document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object**

I do have an object called FromDate.
What else could be causing this error?

Comment: Is the code running from inside the Iframe, or the hosting page?

Comment: The code-behind is in the iframe. The html is in the hosting page

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `window.parent.document.getElementById()`  instead of `window.top.document.getElementById()`

Comment: Why does window.parent work when window.top does not?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `parent.document.getElementById(...)`? Just an idea...

*Edited as suggested by pimvdb*

Comment: `parent` is not a property of `document` but of `window`. Plus, it returns a window, so it should read `parent.document.getElementById`.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I obviously typed it the wrong way around. Fixed in as second.